# Are long-suffix and unsigned-suffix needed when declaring long literals in C++?

Tags: c++, c, literals

I have some ancient memories of writing C code like:

```
long value = 0;
```

in the bad old Win16 days and ending up with `value` being only half-initialized: i.e. the lower 16 bits were `0` and the upper 16 bits were whatever random bits were at that location in memory. As such, I became conditioned to write:

```
long value = 0L;
```

Is this still required in this day-and-age under C99 and/or C++? I know that ILP32 specifies that `int` and `long` are both 32-bit, but suppose we're using, say, LP64 where `int`s are 32-bits and `long`s are 64-bits. Are the suffixes required or will the modern forms of C and C++ implicitly extend literals to the length of the variable they're being assigned to?

How about unsigned values? I.e. is this required?

```
unsigned long value = 0UL;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values)

Answer (score 7):

They are not required in the examples you gave. However, they may be needed in some somewhat recondite circumstances. For example, the following may produce different values:

```
sizeof(1)
sizeof(1L)
```

Comment: @Martin: really? Surely on a website like this, which tries to educate its readers, even a simple yes/no question requires some explanation.

Comment: Examples using 32-bit gcc -std=c99:  sizeof(1) == 4, but sizeof(1LL) == 8

Answer (score 3):

No this should not be required any more.  The behavior you are describing, if visible in the program and not just the debugger, is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are presuming a 32-bit compiler, you may not need L as you did when using a 16-bit compiler, but you could need LL, e.g.:

```
long long ll;
ll = 1<<32;
```

gcc -std=c99 warns "left shift count >= width of type."  Instead, you'd want:

```
ll = 1LL<<32;
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108658/782738, for C++11 and C99 standard references.

Answer (score 1):

But this notation is required for wchar_t strings, like

```
L"I am a wchar_t string."
```

and for long long integers, too...

I guess this is something that should be removed, it isn't useful (the type is declared with its name and not with some suffix), but still supported in C++11.

Hm.