# what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values

Tags: c, constants

From an Example

```
unsigned long x = 12345678UL
```

We have always learnt that the compiler needs to see only "long" in the above example to set 4 bytes (in 32 bit) of memory. The question is why is should we use L/UL in long constants even after declaring it to be a long.

Comment: Do you mean why `UL` is used instead of `L` or instead of nothing?

Comment: @NikosChantziaras No. Why do we need to use L/UL in long values.

Comment: @Patrick This question is for C. That question is for C++ and the accepted answer is about overloading. This is not a duplicate of that.

Comment: Pascal is correct, this question is *not* a duplicate of the linked question.  Nominating to reopen.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

When a suffix `L` or `UL` is not used, the compiler uses the first type that can contain the constant from a list (see details in C99 standard, clause 6.4.4:5. For a decimal constant, the list is `int`, `long int`, `long long int`).

As a consequence, most of the times, it is not necessary to use the suffix. It does not change the meaning of the program. It does not change the meaning of your example initialization of `x` for most architectures, although it would if you had chosen a number that could not be represented as a `long long`. See also codebauer's answer for an example where the `U` part of the suffix is necessary.

---

There are a couple of circumstances when the programmer may want to set the type of the constant explicitly. One example is when using a variadic function:

```
printf("%lld", 1LL); // correct, because 1LL has type long long
printf("%lld", 1);   // undefined behavior, because 1 has type int
```

---

A common reason to use a suffix is ensuring that the result of a computation doesn't overflow. Two examples are:

```
long x = 10000L * 4096L;
unsigned long long y = 1ULL << 36;
```

In both examples, without suffixes, the constants would have type `int` and the computation would be made as `int`. In each example this incurs a risk of overflow. Using the suffixes means that the computation will be done in a larger type instead, which has sufficient range for the result.

As Lightness Races in Orbit puts it, the litteral's suffix comes **before** the assignment. In the two examples above, simply declaring `x` as `long` and `y` as `unsigned long long` is not enough to prevent the overflow in the computation of the expressions assigned to them.

---

Another example is the comparison `x < 12U` where variable `x` has type `int`. Without the `U` suffix, the compiler types the constant `12` as an `int`, and the comparison is therefore a comparison of signed ints.

```
int x = -3;
printf("%d\n", x < 12); // prints 1 because it's true that -3 < 12
```

With the `U` suffix, the comparison becomes a comparison of unsigned ints. “Usual arithmetic conversions” mean that -3 is converted to a large unsigned int:

```
printf("%d\n", x < 12U); // prints 0 because (unsigned int)-3 is large
```

In fact, the type of a constant may even change the result of an arithmetic computation, again because of the way “usual arithmetic conversions” work.

---

Note that, for decimal constants, the list of types suggested by C99 does not contain `unsigned long long`. In C90, the list ended with the largest standardized unsigned integer type at the time (which was `unsigned long`). A consequence was that the meaning of some programs was changed by adding the standard type `long long` to C99: the same constant that was typed as `unsigned long` in C90 could now be typed as a signed `long long` instead. I believe this is the reason why in C99, it was decided not to have `unsigned long long` in the list of types for decimal constants.
See [this](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/20/Constants-quiz) and [this](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/20/Constants-quiz-answers) blog posts for an example.

Comment: Small addition: it can also improve readability and hint about the suggested usage in some cases. E.g. you might have something like `#define MY_DEFINE 123456789UL` and you use `MY_DEFINE` later in the code. Naturally, it doesn't have type associated with it so `UL` addition may be of little help here.

Comment: Even though the compiler can pick the size of a numeric literal, it doesn't automatically determine whether it's signed or not. For example, `18446744073709551615` is treated as `-1L` on systems with a 64-bit `long`. You have to explicitly use `UL`.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras Perhaps at the same time you were writing your comment, I was expanding on the case of the list of types for decimal constants not containing any unsigned types, with a theory for the reason.

Comment: Another fairly common scenario where type suffixes are needed are bit shifts, `1 << 36` is probably UB, `1ULL << 36` is safe. Perhaps worth to be added in the list of examples.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have grouped that with caf's multiplication example.

Comment: IMHO it would be justified to mention the `*_C` macros in `stdint.h` in this answer as well. It's already quite verbose ;) E.g. `UINT64_C(x)` produces a literal of value x with the right suffix to make its type `uint64_t` - thus there is no need for specific prefixes for the `stdint.h` data types.

Comment: @stefanct You can put this information in your own answer if you think it is useful. Re-reading the question, I think it's a digression. There is nothing in the question that indicates that the OP wants to know about the `_C` macro. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @pascal Cuoq:  I am getting correct result for this: signed long long var3 = 2147483648+2; In this case both operands in RHS are ints and result is int and must overflow right? But result is 2147483650. This was using C++11.

Comment: @Rajesh No, `2147483648` is not an `int`

Comment: @pascal Cuoq :  I think I got it. Default integer type literal could be int, long or long long depending on the value of the literal.
     In the case of 
     unsigned long  var1=4294967299*2;
     4294967299 is considered as long long.
     2 is promoted to long long and hence
     4294967299*2 = 8589934598.
     Since LHS is unsigned long, truncation occurs and hence
     Result = 8589934598 - 4294967296 - 4294967296 = 6. Hope I am right.

Comment: @Rajesh You are entirely correct. On most architectures, `4294967299*2` is a well-defined expression, of type `long` or `long long` (`long` if `long` is 64-bit). On the other hand `2000000000*3` is an expression of type `int` that contains undefined behavior, because `2000000000` is typed as `int` and the multiplication overflows. It's a funny language.

Answer (score 21):

Because numerical literals are of typicaly of type int. The UL/L tells the compiler that they  are not of type int, e.g. assuming 32bit int and 64bit long

```
long i = 0xffff;
long j = 0xffffUL;
```

Here the values on the right must be converted to signed longs (32bit -> 64bit)

1. The "0xffff", an int, would converted to a long using sign extension, resulting in a negative value (0xffffffff)
2. The "0xffffUL", an unsigned long, would be converted to a long, resulting in a positive value (0x0000ffff)

Comment: Never thought about the printf. I work lots with arm, and have seen some 'interesting' vargs problems...

Comment: I believe there is an example in there, but the details seem slightly off: 1) Hexadecimal constants are typed from another list that includes unsigned types 2) 0xffff is too small to set the sign bit on a 32-bit int 3) if a positive constant does not fit in a signed type without setting the sign bit, the next type in the list is tried. I tried to make a verified example, but I couldn't find the right constants.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Disagree that this is a _nice_ example. with C99, `0xffff` is an `int` with the value of 65,535.  Assigning that to `i` is not an issue. `0xffffUL` is an `unsigned long` with the value of 65,535.  Assigning that to `j` is also not an issue.  Had this example been `long i = 0xffffffff;` `0xffffffff` is an `unsigned` with the value of 4,294,967,295 and assigning that to 64-`long` is not an issue.  Also a non-issue with `long j = 0xffffffffUL;`  This answer's #1 "converted to a long using sign extension" is not true here.

Comment: @chux You should argue with someone who said it were then. Why did you mention me? Please stop.

Comment: To answer your [querry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values/13135343?noredirect=1#comment67867980_13135343), I mentioned you in  [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values/13135343?noredirect=1#comment67791889_13135343) in response to [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values/13135343?noredirect=1#comment17864303_13135343)

Comment: @chux “Hey, in a 2012 discussion you said that an example of weird C behavior was nice at 8:42 before relenting and explaining why the example doesn't work at 9:50. Please let me explain to you now in 2016 at great length all the things that you have already shown you understand four years ago” “No thanks”

Answer (score 13):

> The question is why is should we use L/UL in long constants even after declaring it to be a long.

Because it's not "after"; it's "before".

First you have the literal, *then* it is converted to whatever the type is of the variable you're trying to squeeze it into.

They are two objects. The type of the target is designated by the `unsigned long` keywords, as you've said. The type of the source is designated by this suffix because that's the only way to specify the type of a literal.

Comment: I wish we could write `LUL` instead of `ULL` :)

Comment: @TornaxO7 the C standard really missed a golden opportunity there. Maybe C23 can change that.

Answer (score 2):

Related to this post is why a `u`.

A reason for `u` is to allow an *integer constant* greater than `LLONG_MAX` in decimal form.

```
// Likely to generate a warning.
unsigned long long limit63bit = 18446744073709551615; // 2^64 - 1

// OK
unsigned long long limit63bit = 18446744073709551615u;
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65007935/4688119