# Why am I getting a return value of -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)?

Tags: c

I have very recently started to learn c, my first coding language. I am trying to solve problem 3 from Project Euler, and I wrote this to do so. This code is meant to identify the largest prime factor of 600851475143,
but instead I get a strange return value I don't understand. Anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1, a = 0, prime = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 600851475143; i += 2) {
        for(a = 0; a <= i / 2; a++) {
            if(i % a == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if(a = i / 2) {
                if(600851475143 % i == 0) {
                    prime = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", prime );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: How many bits does 600851475143 require for storage?

Comment: Another problem is `if(a = i / 2)`.  This is an assignment to `a`, and will be true as long as `i/2` is non-zero.  Presumably you intended it to be `if(a == i / 2)`, which is a comparison.

Comment: Get `-Wall` to compiler option and you'll know most of your mistakes.

Comment: @JAB `int i; ... i < 600851475143` is a _very_ legitimate concern about the lack of `int i` range, yet OP's code problem first occurs  with the attempt to do `i%0`.

Answer (score 3):

Division by 0 (or trying to `%0`).  This is *undefined behavior* (UB) and can explain the return of -1.  With UB - *anything* can happen.
 The rest of code is not important until this is fixed.

```
for(a = 0; a <= i / 2; a++) {
  //     v---- a is zero!
  if(i % a == 0) {
```

Code probably should start as 2.

```
// for(a = 0; a <= i / 2; a++) {
for(a = 2; a <= i / 2; a++) {
```

Rather than end at `i / 2`, end at the √600851475143,  it is *much* sooner.

```
           v-------------------v Same a <= sqrt(600851475143) without FP or overflow
for(a = 2; a <= 600851475143 / a; a++) {
```

Other issues exist too.  `if(a = i / 2)` see [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585508/why-am-i-getting-a-return-value-of-1-0xffffffff/47585607#comment82128865_47585508)

`int` likely has a range well within 600851475143, so `i < 600851475143` is always true.  A common compiler warning will emit this.  Be sure to fully enable warnings to save time. [@iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585508/why-am-i-getting-a-return-value-of-1-0xffffffff/47585607#comment82129287_47585508)

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
```

---

Pseudo code solution

```
int main(void) {
  wide_enough_type n = 600851475143;
  wide_enough_type factor = 1;
  try each i starting at 2 and until  i*i <= n
    repeat as long as n divides into i with no remainder
      make n smaller by diving it by i
      save i as factor
  save the larger of (n, factor) as factor
  printf("Greatest factor: %some_type_specifier\n", factor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is called an *overflow*. All data types have limited range, due to the limited amout of memory available. An `int`, on an average modern computer, goes usually up to 2,147,483,647 (WARNING: I said usually) - things are in reality a bit more complex. Anyway, your upper limit exceeds this.

What happens when an `int` (or a signed integer data type) overflows is that, due to some representation related issues, it goes negative. Have a look at *two's complement representation* for more details about why.

To fix it, use a data type with a broader range. `long long` goes up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, which seems suitable for your needs.

Note that the integer literals need also to be marked as `long long`, otherwise they will overflow too:

```
for(i = 1; i < 600851475143LL; i += 2)
```

If you need integer values larger than the range supported by `long long` (it doesn't seem to be the case here though), you're out of luck: you need to find some clever way to deal with it.

Something else to look for is that when I ran the code I got a division by 0. I do not know if this is related to the overflow or not.

Comment: `i % a` will be a division by zero when `a == 0`

Comment: "integer literals need also to be marked as long long, otherwise they will overflow too:" --> No.  `LL` not needed.

Comment: [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135192/2410359) may help detail about the lack of need for `LL`.