# How does constant integer assignment in c++

Tags: c++, integer, constants, numeric

could any please explain the below code

```
const uInt32 eVal = 8ul;
const uInt32 fVal = 5ul;
const uInt32 zVal = 0ul;
```

what does ul and numbers 8,5,0 are stand for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values)

Answer (score 4):

It's the programmer being unnecessarily verbose. `ul` is the prefix for an `unsigned long` literal, so `8ul` has an `unsigned long` type.

Most likely, that isn't the same type as the `uInt32`, so really the code you present is an exercise in obfuscation. Really they should rely on the automatic *implicit conversion rules* and write

```
const uInt32 eVal = 8;
const uInt32 fVal = 5;
const uInt32 zVal = 0;
```

perhaps even preferring `constexpr` in place of `const`.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Answer (score 2):

ul stands for unsigned long representation of numbers.  Here the number 8 or 5 or 0 of type unsigned long is being assigned to constant uInt32 type variable.

The 'ul' is used for representation. It need not be used also.