# Shifting on Integer Constants shows warning. How to clear this?

Tags: c

Reference: [Suffix in Integer Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values#:%7E:text=A%20common%20reason%20to%20use,would%20be%20made%20as%20int%20.)

```
unsigned long long y = 1 << 33;
```

Results in warning:

```
left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
```

Two Questions need to be cleared from the above context:

1. unsigned long long type has 64-bit, why cant we do left shift in it?
2. how shifting works in int constants('1')?

Comment: Think of it this way: the compiler looks at the expression `1<<33` on its own first. Only once that is evaluated it looks at what it needs to do with the result. The type of the left hand sign of the assignment doesn't come into play until it is "too late" in this case.

Comment: If you want to reference another question, please make sure to *link* to that question. Please read [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to create links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C language, 1 is an `int` which is 32 bits on most platforms. When you try to shift it 33 bits *before* storing its value in an `unsigned long long`, that's not going to end well. You can fix this in 2 ways:

- Use `1ULL` instead, which is an `unsigned long long` constant:

```
unsigned long long y = 1ULL << 33;
```

- Assign the value, then shift it:

```
unsigned long long y = 1;
y <<= 33;
```

Both are valid, but I'd suggest the first one since it's shorter and you can make `y` const.

Comment: And why the value '1' is considered as a integer constant by default. If so, if overwrite any value, it is changing. Constants could not be changed?

Comment: @sat.learner because the standard says so. Integer literals without any suffices that are small enough to fit into an `int` have the type `int`. If you want them to have any other type, use appropriate suffices like `ULL`.

Comment: Can we overwrite the integer constant? After we chosen the right constant type.

Comment: @sat.learner I am not sure what you mean by "overwrite". Do you want `1` to be an `unsigned long long` without `ULL`?

Comment: If this line compiled: unsigned long long y = 1ULL << 33; 
It's means that, y has a constant integer value. We can't able to change it. How the shift operator works in a constant value. It will not work(considering the value as constant). How compiler reads it as int value. ( If we are telling that it's a constant value. Then how we relate this with using 'const': const unsigned long long y =1ULL.)

Comment: @sat.learner It's not because `1` is const. It's because `1` is a literal. `const unsigned long long y = 1;` has the type `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Detail: C calls `1` a _constant_ , not a literal nor a `const`.  C specifies 2 literals: string and complex, not any others.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica hmm, interesting. It's called [Integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for C++ and [Integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) for C.

Comment: In C, the address can be taken of a literal, but not a constant. `char (*a)[] = &"hello"; int *b = &(int){42};` vs. `int *c_invalid = &123;`.