# C++ suffix L vs specifying long double

Tags: c++

Question [What does the "L" mean at the end of an integer literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958007/what-does-the-l-mean-at-the-end-of-an-integer-literal) describes what `L` means at the end of int literal. I am confused why not to specify `long int i = 33` instead of `int i = 33L`? The same thing applies to other types. Instead of specifying `double b = 3.0L` why not to write `long double`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: Sometimes you are not assigning to a variable, but using it as a term in an expression. This can be used to force a widening conversion, for example.

Comment: If you're using `auto` instead of a specific type, the literal will deduce to the correct type.

Comment: `int i = 33L` is not declaring a `long int`. It is declaring an `int` that is initialized with a sloppy narrowing cast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values)

Comment: [Why do you need to append an L or F after a value assigned to a C++ constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380653/995714), [Are long-suffix and unsigned-suffix needed when declaring long literals in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/975942/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused why not to specify long int i = 33 instead of int i = 33L?

Because that 2 statements mean 2 different things:

```
long int i = 33; // take constant of type int, convert it to long int and assign to i.

int i = 33L; // take constant of type long int, convert it to int and assign to i.
```

So you end up with variable `i` of different type. Same for the double in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Although in many instances, you can rely on the extremely well-defined widening conversion rules, sometimes you need to be explicit about the *type* of a literal.

For example

```
long double f = 1.0;
f = std::max(f, 2.0L);
```

does not compile unless the arguments of `max` have the same type. Writing `double b = 3.0L` would indeed be pointless, and a compiler will almost certainly ignore you and compile `double b = 3.0`.